# Load items asynchronously to a ListView after navigation to Page Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app in which I have a button that Navigates to `PageTwo.xaml`. In that `PageTwo.xaml.cs`, in the code behind I have something like this:

```
string type = "";

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    type = e.Parameter.ToString();          
}

private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    PageTwoListViewModel pageTwoListViewModel = ViewModelLocator.PageTwoListStatic;
    this.DataContext = pageTwoListViewModel;
}
```

The reason I'm setting the `DataContext` in the Page_Loaded event is because the project is a ClassLibrary and I have no `App.xaml` file, but that shouldn't affect anything related to my problem.

Then in my `PageTwoViewModel` I have the following:

```
public RelayCommand PageLoadedCommand { get; private set; }

public PageTwoListViewModel() {
    this.PageLoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(PageLoaded);
}

private void PageLoaded() {
    LoadList();
}

private async void LoadList() {
    ObservableCollection<MyListModel> _list = await DatabaseService.GetList();
    MyViewList = _list;
}
```

The code responsible for triggering the PageLoadedCommand is:

```
<Page (...)>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PageLoadedCommand}">
            </core:InvokeCommandAction>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Page>
```

The problem here is that the `OnNavigatedTo` and both `Page_Loaded` events run before the Page is visible, so if I have a big list to fill, only after everything is done does it go to `PageTwo.xaml`, freezing the application.
What I want to do is to navigate to `PageTwo.xaml` and when there, fire up a loading animation and fill my ListView asynchronously. How can I do this?

Comment: When your PageLoadedCommand if fired now?

Comment: The fire order is: OnNavigatedTo -> Page_Loaded -> PageLoadedCommand(PageLoaded)

Comment: i mean which code exactly fires this command?

Comment: Oh, ok, didn't get that. I'll add the to the main question.

Comment: How many list items are we talking about here? What's the nature of `DatabaseService.GetList()`? Is it truly asynchronous? I'm thinking, maybe your database service is blocking the UI thread somehow. Need more information.

Comment: The ORM I was using for the Database calls was not entirely asynchronous, so that was in fact the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, my problem came from a rather stupid thing. My `DatabaseService.GetList();` was not entirely asynchronous, and that was what was causing the problem, so the above implementation works just fine as long as you guarantee the Database calls are asynchronous.